# Java FX How to style an item in a ListView if changed

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I have a ***ListView*** of users that can be *on/off*.

I found a method to style each cell based on some condition:

```
friends.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String friendname, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(friendname, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        setStyle("");
                    } else {
                        setText(friendname);
                        if (usersService.isOnline(friendname)) {
                            do stuf....
                        }
                    }
                }
});
```

Is there a method so I can call this method each time an user goes on or off? Other then using a thread, because I see it creates a new List each time it is called...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create something you can observe, and observe it...

E.g. if your `usersService` has an `ObservableList<String> onlineUsers`, containing a list of the usernames of everyone who's online, you can do:

```
friends.setCellFactory(lv -> {

    ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String friendname, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(friendname, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setStyle("");
            } else {
                setText(friendname);
            }
        }

    };

    cell.styleProperty().bind(new StringBinding() {
        { bind(cell.itemProperty(), usersService.getOnlineUsers()); }
        @Override
        protected String computeValue() {
            if (cell.getItem() == null) {
                return "" ;
            }
            if (usersService.getOnlineUsers().contains(cell.getItem())) {
                return "/* online style here */";
            }
            return "/* offline style here*/" ;
        }
    });

    return cell ;

});
```

Then whenever the list of online users changes, the cell will update accordingly.

You can simplify this by using an external CSS file and a custom `PseudoClass`:

```
PseudoClass online = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("online");

friends.setCellFactory(lv -> {

    ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String friendname, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(friendname, empty);
            setText(friendname);
        }

    };

    InvalidationListener listener = obs -> 
        cell.pseudoClassStateChanged(online, 
            cell.getItem() != null
            && usersService.getOnlineUsers().contains(cell.getItem()));
    cell.itemProperty().addListener(listener);
    usersService.getOnlineUsers().addListener(listener);

    return cell ;

});
```

Then in your CSS file do

```css
.list-cell {
    /* offline style rules here */
}
.list-cell:online {
    /* online style rules here */
}
```

Comment: Great elegant solution! Thank you sir! Works like a charm!